# How to use Singularity in docker container?

Tags: docker, snakemake, singularity-container

I have a question about the official Snakemake container image.
https://hub.docker.com/r/snakemake/snakemake/dockerfile

In this Dockerfile, singularity will be installed. As far as I know, the `--privileged` argument seems to be required to use singularity in a docker container.
`docker run -it --privileged snakemake/snakemake ........`

However, I think the `--privileged` argument is insecure from a security standpoint, so it would be preferable not to use it if possible.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to use singularity in a docker container?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--privileged` flag is the recommended and only way to run singularity in Docker.

Use of `--privileged` is not bad in itself, it is also used for running Docker-in-Docker, but it does allow the *possibility* of container escape. Follow best practices, build your own images and you should be okay.

Comment: It seems this answer is unfinished. "Use of `--privileged` is not insecure in". In what ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I understand that `--privileged` flag is the only way to do it. And here's what I want to make sure of.  

> "*possibility* of container escape"     
This means an attacker gets through the container and accesses the host?  
> "Follow best practices"  
This means *Best practices for writing Dockerfiles* and I should creating the user and group in the Dockerfile with something like `RUN groupadd -r postgres && useradd --no-log-init -r -g postgres postgres` ??

Thanks,

Comment: If a malicious user is able to escape the container, they will have root on the host OS. You always need the `privileged` flag when running singularity, but running singularity images does not require root and you should use the docker `--user` flag (e.g., to the `postgres` user you mention).

Comment: I now understand why you would set the general user instead of the root when using singularity.    It was very helpful. Thank you very much.